# Knex - NodeJS Dúvida (GraphQL)

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql, knex.js

Quero retornar todos os meus dados desta tabela no meu banco. Estou fazendo a seguinte consulta:

```
async licitacaoAll(_, { dados }) {
  if (!dados) return null
  const { ativo } = dados

  return await db('licitacao as l').where({ 'l.ativo': ativo })
}
```

No console ele mostra todos os dados, mas no resultados (*playground*), mostra apenas `null`. Como faço para mostrar todos os elementos lá no playground do GraphQL?

O que o `console` loga:

```
RowDataPacket {
    id_licitacao: 277,
    id_unidade: 10,
    modalidade: 34,
    tipo: 303,
    numero: 7,
    ano: 2016,
    tramite_atual: 342,
    descricao: 'RP - Material Hospitalar',
    dt_abertura: 2016-04-01T03:00:00.000Z,
    hora: '08:30',
    nome_arquivo: null,
    tamanho: null,
    url_amigavel: '277-licitacao-RP - Material Hospitalar...',
    num_retirada: 0,
    mostra_data: 1,
    cadastrado_por: 81,
    dt_cadastro: 2016-02-15T14:27:32.000Z,
    atualizado_por: 49,
    dt_atualizado: 2016-03-14T11:29:29.000Z,
    ativo: 1,
    excluido: 0 }, // ...
}
```

O que o *playground* retorna:

```js
{
  "data": {
    "licitacaoAll": null
  }
}
```

E o *schema*:

```
type Licitacao {
    id_licitacao: Int
    id_unidade: Int
    modalidade: Int
    tipo: Int
    numero: Int
    ano: Int
    tramite_atual: Int
    descricao: String
    dt_abertura: String
    hora: String
    nome_arquivo: String
    tamanho: String
    url_amigavel: String
    num_retirada: Int
    mostra_data: String
    cadastrado_por: Int
    dt_cadastro: String
    atualizado_por: Int
    dt_atualizado: String
    ativo: Int
    excluido: Int
}

input LicitacaoFiltro {
    id_licitacao: Int
}

input LicitacaoAll {
    ativo: Int
}
```

Comment: Tente fazer um `console.log` dos resultados da _query_ antes de retorná-los. Penso que provavelmente a query não está retornando nenhum valor... É isso?

Comment: Aí que tá, no console.log() funciona, mostra todos os dados, só que no Playgroung não vem, mostra apenas null

Comment: Edite a sua pergunta adicionando os dados retornados pelo `console.log` e _Schema_ do seu GraphQL...